# Send push notification for one app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

I have many application on android. And some users are share the same register ID. How can I specify and send the push notification to a specific app?

Answer (score 1):

Different applications have different registration ids on the same device, so you shouldn't have any problem. What do you mean by `users are share the same register ID`? Do you mean users of the same application on the same device? That's the only case where they can share a registration ID.

Even if you use the same Google API project ID when you register the different Apps for Google Cloud Messaging, you'll still get a different registration ID for each app. I tested it.

Comment: I mean user with two different apps share the same register id

Comment: @mostashaar A user with two different apps will have a different registration id for each app.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the registration ID process to uniquely identify you applications (the best solution), you can send a [payload](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#payload) with your GCM message and have your application ignore GCM messages without a specific payload.